# How to implement animation between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957559/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-a-web-site-that-contains-a-single-pa) not to create a single page website.

However, I would like to create animation effects between tabs like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/PZ6xL/).

How this can be done if I have a separate HTML for each tab ?

Or maybe you have a better approach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes! it's not good to use single page...

for me (just a theory and not been tested), how about this?

**1** . make all the pages... (index.html, about-us.html, etc...). 
 **2** . make the menu like the usual way...

```
<ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  
     <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>  
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>  
</ul>
```

**3** . by jQuery edit each <a>'s href like this

```
$('ul.menu a').attr('href', function(i,v){ return '#' + v })
      .click(function(){
           openTab(this.href.replace('#',''));
      })
openTab(window.location.href.replace('#','')); // call in all pages for bookmark purpose
function openTab(url){
   $('#content').slideUp();
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: 'get',
      success: function(html){
         // find the content to be displayed
         $('#content').html(html.find('#content').contents())
            .slideDown(); // then animate....
      }
   })
}
```

hope you got the idea.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For each tab at the top (where you click), you'll probably have a link of some sort.

1. Create a function to change the tabs when you click it; e.g. `showTab(tab)`
2. Attach that function using an onClick event onto each of the links

The function showTab(tabId) can do the following:

```
function showTab(tabId) {
    $('.tabs').slideUp();
    $('#' + tabId).slideDown();
}
```

The links can have inline onclick events like this:

```
<a id="contactlink" href="#" onclick="showTab('contactlink'); return false;">Contact up</a>
...
```

If you want fancier animations, you can also use the jQuery .animate function.

See here: [jQuery Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

Comment: A few things here, inline event handlers are border-line evil (just kidding but seriously there's no need), and your example would mean that the tab had the same ID as the anchor, also invalid.  Here's an example of what you're after with no inline script, less overall code and falls back in javascript is disabled: http://jsfiddle.net/fNJDj/

Comment: hi Nick, but I guess, your example would be just a one page site... ;) and the OP has second thoughts on that... ;)